# Какие еще сообщества на русском кроме программирования и мета в этой системе?

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange

Какие еще сообщества на русском кроме программирования и мета в этой системе?

Comment: Убрал метку [tag:предложение], т.к. не вижу явно сформулированного предложения.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Свой мета-сайт есть у каждого сайта сети Stack Exchange. На русском ещё есть:

- [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) + Мета. Вопросы о русском языке, сайт ориентирован на носителей языка (т.е. на тех, для кого русский язык — родной).
- [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) + Мета. Вопросы о русском языке, основной язык — английский, но можно и на русском спрашивать и отвечать. Сайт ориентирован на изучающих русский язык.

На этом всё. Других сайтов/сообществ на русском нет и пока что не планируется (["not yet"](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-se-2-0-sites-edition)).

Comment: Можно упомянуть, что тематика ruSO уже шире enSO—не только программирование. Более того не ясно, есть ли польза от фрагментации сообщества, то есть возможно следует расширять тематику ruSO далее вместо создания крошечных аналогов Ask Ubuntu, Ask Different, Mathematics и даже Super User и Software Engineering ("Programmers")—при повышенном требовании к качеству вопросов—и даже Physics, Electrical Engineering итд. Метки позволяют легко избежать/найти подобные вопросы.

Comment: @jfs думаю, что по крайней мере в рамках IT-тематики фрагментировать не нужно, это будет только во вред. В целом согласен, дополню.